# A lower bound for $(1-e^x)^n$

Tags: calculus, inequality, exponential-function, binomial-theorem, upper-lower-bounds

I want to find a lower bound for 
$$(1-e^x)^n$$
$n$ integer, $x$ real, and $1-e^x\geq 0$. One  lower bound is (Bernoulli's inequality)
$$(1-e^x)^n\geq 1-ne^x$$ But I need a tighter lower bound that is polynomial in $n$ and $x$.

I am thinking of combining binomial expansion of $(1-e^x)^n$ and Taylor series of $e^x$, but that gets too complicated. I am wondering if there exists any tight lower bound for this  that I am not aware of. Any help/hint is  appreciated.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean when you say you want a tighter lower bound?  The Bernoulli bound is tight as $x \to -\infty$ for fixed $n$ (in that $\lim_{x \to -\infty} (1-e^x)^n = 0 = \lim_{x \to -\infty} 1-ne^x$), while no nontrivial polynomial bound can have this property, as A. Pongrácz mentions.

Comment: If you fix $n$, this is going to behave like $(-1)^n e^{xn}$ for large positive $x$, and for negative $x$ it will quickly flatline at the line $y = 1$. So for negative $x$ the function is not that interesting, and for positive $x$ the function is the exponential $(-1)^n e^{xn}$. 

(In fact, for odd $n$, $(-1)^n e^{xn}$ will decrease faster than any polynomial so no polynomial lower bound exists. For even $n$, every polynomial will be a lower bound eventually as $e^{xn}$ overtakes it.)

Comment: @A.Pongrácz. $e^x\geq x$ is a polynomial lower bound for an exponential function.

Comment: @A. Pongrácz Note that the OP only requires the bound in the region $1 - e^x \ge 0$ (i.e. $x \le 0$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't.

> There is no polynomial $f(n,x)$ in $n$ and $x$ such that there exist positive $c\in\Bbb R$ such that for any $x\lt -c$ and any $n\in\Bbb Z$, $$(1-e^x)^n\ge f(n,x)\geq 1-ne^x$$

For the sake of contradiction, let $f(n,x)$ be such a polynomial. Let $n=1$. We will have for x sufficient small, $1-e^x\ge f(1,x)\geq 1-e^x$. That is, $f(1,x)=1-e^x$, which cannot be true.

OK, you may say $n=1$ is an outlier. Let us exclude that outlier. However, we have a stronger statement.

> Let $1\neq n\in\Bbb N$. There is no polynomial $f(x)$ such that there exist positive $c\in\Bbb R$ such that for any $x\lt -c$, $$(1-e^x)^n\ge f(x)\geq 1-ne^x$$

Here is a simple proof. For the sake of contradiction, let $f(x)$ be such a polynomial. Taking $x$ to $-\infty$, we find that $f(x)$ goes to 1. As a polynomial in $x$, $f(x)$ must be the constant polynomial $1$. Then for any $x$ and positive $n$, $(1-e^x)^n<1=f(x)$.

(So, it seems there is some typo or lapse in the question since its answer is almost trivially false)

Comment: See the comments, please.

Comment: @A.Pongrácz, yes, I have. Of course, I agree the larger background is how to approximate exponential function with polynomial by inequalities. I would not go that dense before confirming and clearing OP's typo or lapse if any.

Comment: It was pointed out that I have overseen a condition. But still, wouldn't it be simpler to say that the only bounded polynomials are constants? This is essentially what you did, I just think your argument was too detailed. But anyway, you are right.

Comment: @A.Pongrácz, well, we have to say something like the only bounded single(-real)-variable polynomials over an arbitrary large interval are constants. That becomes a bit vague, risking being wrong, although it is indeed correct. That is, indeed, in a better form for human understanding and simpler to say